# react typescript how to configure routes.ts file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I just started working with typescript so don't be mad on me.

I'm trying to configure routes.ts file. But i'm getting a bunch of errors.Could you please help me with them:

1. inside AppPath component "Type '{ path: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key" error
2. inside AppRoutes component "Type '"/admin"' is not assignable to type 'Switch'."

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

import Admin from './admin/Admin';
import Imitator from './imitator/Imitator';

import ImitatorLayout from './admin/layout/index';
import AdminLayout from './imitator/layout';


type AppPathProps = {
  component: RouteComponentProps,
  layout: FunctionComponent,
  path:string
};

const AppPath = ({ component, layout, path }: AppPathProps): JSX.Element => {
  const Component = component;
  const Layout = layout;

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
  render = {(props: RouteComponentProps) => (
  <Layout>
  <Component { ...props } />
  </Layout>
)}
/>
  );
};

const AppRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
  <AppPath path= "/admin" component = { Admin } layout = { AdminLayout } />
    <AppPath path="/" component = { Imitator } layout = { ImitatorLayout } />
      </Switch>
);

export default AppRoutes;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's an additional reason for extending the Route, you would just do:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const Imitator: React.FC = props => {
   render <div>Imitator/div>
};

const Admin: React.FC = props => {
   render <div>App</div>
};

const AppRoutes = () => (<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Imitator} />
      <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>);
```